# Escaped ! displays as literal \!

Tags: bash, escaping, punctuation

I'm trying to write a Python program to a file in one line of Bash. I am trying this:

```
$ printf "#\!/usr/bin/python3\nprint('hi\!')\nwhatever()" > whatever.py
```

But that gives:

```
#\!/usr/bin/python3
print('Hi\!')
whatever()
```

How can I get it to output:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
print('Hi!')
whatever()
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to use a [Here Document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```
cat > whatever.py <<EndOfPythonProgram
#!/usr/bin/python3
print('hi!')
whatever()
EndOfPythonProgram
```

But since you wanted to write everything in one line, you may use the following command:

```
printf '%s\n' '#!/usr/bin/python3' "print('hi"'!'"')" 'whatever()' > whatever.py
```

- First, we use `printf %s yourString` instead of `printf yourString`. That's the way `printf` is supposed to be used (not necessary in this case, but safer for general cases).
- With `%s\n` every additional argument of `printf` is printed as one line.
- In the first line, there are no single quotes, so we can quote the whole first line in single quotes and don't have to escape the `!`.
- In the second line, there are single quotes, so we cannot quote the whole second line in single quotes. Nevertheless, we can quote the `!` in single quotes and the remaining parts in double quotes. In `bash` the string `ab` can be written as: `ab`, `"ab"`, `'ab'`, `"a"'b'`, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
set +H # disable history expansion

printf "#!/usr/bin/python3\nprint('hi!')\nwhatever()\n"

set -H # enable history expansion again
```

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
print('hi!')
whatever()
```

Comment: another way without changing settings moving `!` out from quotes : `printf "#"\!"/usr/bin/python3\nprint('hi"\!"')\nwhatever()"`, or if expansion not needed using ANSI-C quotes `echo $'#!/usr/bin/python3\nprint(\'hi\')\nwhatever()'`